# Update on a subset of embedded documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Given the following db

```
{
    "type":"s",
    "disp":[
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141109
        },
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141110
        },
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141111
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type":"d",
    "disp":[
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141109
        },
        {
            "quantity":0,
            "date":20141110
        },
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141111
        }
    ]
}
```

I perform a query to obtain a "type" with quantity grater then 0 for a set of dates

```
db.test.find({ "$and" : [
    { "disp" : { "$elemMatch" : { "quantity" : { "$gt" : 0 }, "date" : 20141109 } } },
    { "disp" : { "$elemMatch" : { "quantity" : { "$gt" : 0 }, "date" : 20141110 } } }
] },{"type":1})
```

I get the type "s" then I want to decrement by 1 only the quantity for the dates I just queried

I tried different kinds of update queries but I was able to change just one quantity field.

How can I do that in an atomic way ?
If it's not possible can you advise me on a way to structure my data to query and atomically update quantity for specific dates ?

Answer (score 1):

You can update **only** a single matching sub document in MongoDb, even if multiple sub documents match the query. Currently it is a limitation.

To update all the sub documents for each date, you need to fire `n` update queries to update documents for `n` different matching dates.

You need to make use of the [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) and the positional update [$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operators.

```
var dates = [20141109,20141110];
dates.forEach(function(date){
db.test.update({"type":"s","disp.date":date},
                     {$inc:{"disp.$.quantity":1}})
})
```

Answering your questions:

> *atomically update quantity for specific dates*

As per the documentation,

> $inc is an atomic operation within a single document.

A suggestion:

> *n a way to structure my data to query*

**Never** have two different sub documents for the same date as depicted in the example. If you would have then it makes no sense in updating two different sub documents for the same date.

```
    {
        "quantity":0,
        "date":20141110
    },
    {
        "quantity":1,
        "date":20141110
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if query a document, modify it in memory and update it as a whole isn't better then multiple updates ...
BTW the duplicated dates are a typo, I edited it ;)

Comment: If the number of matching sub documents is significantly large, then yes, its better to handle that in the client side.Modify and Update all the sub documents, Otherwise this is fine.

Comment: I have an issue with concurrency. I have to avoid a two query matching overlapping periods because the first one is partially updating single dates. Otherwise I have to manage a rollback ...